# How to plot a single column using Seaborn?

Tags: seaborn, data-visualization, data-analysis

suppose i have a dataset like this

```
a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
b=np.array([1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4])
```

I want to compare the two dataset and see the difference between them, something like this

[image]

I am not able to find any method in seaborn with which i can achieve this, methods like lineplot or scatterplot requires both x and y axis, can anyone help on this

Comment: Have you found any other methods since then?

Answer (score 0):

i just found out the answer

import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

```
sns.lineplot(data=_a)
```

previously, i was using like this which was causing error

```
sns.lineplot(x=_a)
sns.lineplot(_a)
```